# How can I force gcc to check existence of forward declared classes?

Tags: c++

Adding a not existing class **forward declaration**, like `class Qwertyuiop` compiles and links without error!

I deduce that, the existence of forward declared classes, is NOT checked 
(unless we call a method on it that is not defined).

It looks that they are considered as nothing more than a `void *`.

Considering C/C++ compilation process this makes sense.

But in order to improve **correctness** of program, having a way of **checking existence of forward declared classes** may be useful.

Comment: What kind of errors would that avoid? You already have type-safety (unlike `void*`), and you'll get linker errors if there is a problematic mismatch with the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Just write `static_assert(sizeof(Qwertyuiop)>0, "Qwertyuiop is defined")`.

Obviously you can't check in one Translation Unit whether it's defined in another TU; that's incompatible with separate translation. TU's may be compiled in any order.